# Google Map v2 Animation

Tags: android, google-maps, android-animation, surfaceview

My app is composed of three fragments in an activity left to right. The user can animate to the left or right like a sliding drawer. This works perfectly in all cases except when the MapFragment is visible.

The MapFragment is already instantiated in the TabHost in both cases, but is visible in the 2nd image.

[image: Working Correctly]

[image: MapFragment displayed]

I set a lot of the dimensions programattically, but this is the basic view hierarchy if it helps:

```
<xxxx.xxxx.WideLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/frag_container"
android:layout_width="900dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/left_menu"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/login_blackboard" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/left_list"
        android:name="xxxx.xxxx.MenuFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:tag="MENU" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/middle_menu"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/frag_action"
    android:name="xxx.xxxx.ActionFragment"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</xxxx.xxxx.WideLayout>
```

Any suggestions to keep the map in its bounds after the animation?

Answer (score 0):

Put a transparent layout in frontof the map while you are showing the menu. I don't know why, but it is a redraw problem. Hope that helps ;)